# I want to retrieve the path/filename of the selected java file from the package explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I am developing a plugin that requires retrieval of path/filename of java files.

The code that I have written, successfully retrieves the filenames/path of the xml or manifest files, but is unable to retrieve the path of the Java files in the packages.

The code I have used is :-

```
if (selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)

    {
        Object o = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();
        if (o instanceof IFile) 
        {
            IPath loc = ((IFile) o).getLocation();
            if (loc != null) 
            {
                    selectedFile = loc.toOSString();

            }
            else
                selectedFile = "Error at loc";
        }
        else
            selectedFile = "Error at O";
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'unable'?

Comment: it shows proper path for the files. bt for the java files, it shows "ERROR AT O".

Comment: What about debugging and checking what type `o` is actually of , if it's not an implementor of `IFile`?

Comment: I did try to check, although i was not able to make out the same, what should i be luking for ??

Comment: Well, you might be looking for interfaces that are implemented by the class you actually get (or one of its super classes) and from what I found on the web, you should eventually reach `ICompilationUnit` (see my answer).

Comment: I guess the selection isn't an instanceof IFile then. Maybe you could find out what it *is* an instance of?

Comment: Please don't repost questions, instead edit them to add the required details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS GUYZ, I WAS ABLE TO FIGURE IT OUT WITH YOUR HELP

THE SOLUTION IS -

Object o = ((IStructuredSelection) selection).getFirstElement();

den 
IPath loc = ((ICompilationUnit) o).getPath();

den 
selectedFile = loc.toOSString();

With this, you will be able to get the path of the java file that u selected. and also, this shows the pathname starting from the project name, can someone tell how to get the entire physical pathname, with the drives and such as well..??

Answer (score 0):

Here's a topic from the eclipse forum: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/162556/

It seems like Java source file resources don't implement `IFile` but `ICompilationUnit`, so test for that.

Comment: yea, its written there in debugging. ICompilationUnit. thanx, i will check that one.

Comment: The link above, is not about the selected file resource returning ICompilationUnit. How do i convert the file resource into IPath then, to get the path of the file ?? someone tell that part. please.

Comment: @Hitesh you really need to learn how to search an api. From what I could see, `ICompilationUnit` extends `IJavaElement` and thus provides a `getPath()` method which returns an `IPath`.